# .htaccess shows up | But It doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess

```
/var/www/html/talent-media.com/public_html/help/scp/apps/.htaccess
```

shows up, but there is no .htaccess file as per

```
[root@0rcan0mic apps]# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Apr 28 00:05 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4096 Mar 20 01:11 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1349 Mar 20 01:11 dispatcher.php
[root@0rcan0mic apps]# pwd
/var/www/html/talent-media.com/public_html/help/scp/apps
[root@0rcan0mic apps]#
```

Thoughts?

Comment: check if there is any output after `cat /var/www/html/talent-media.com/public_html/help/scp/apps/.htaccess`

Comment: No such file or directory